# discord bot replies 1 to 2 times

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i am currently working on this discord bot but when i call a command it responds twice. would anyone know how to fix this?

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {

  let prefix = config.prefix;
  let messageArray = message.content.split(' ');
  let command = messageArray[0];
  let args = messageArray.slice(1);
  const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

  if (command === `${prefix}hit`) {
    let user2 = `${args}`
    if (user2 === '')
      user2 = `${bot.user.username}`
    let user1 = message.author
    message.reply(`hit you ${user2} \n https://media.giphy.com/media/43bOrDOasXG6Y/giphy.gif`)
}
})
```

Comment: Do you have multiple terminals open/instances running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried shutting down all other processes of your bot (Google Cloud, AWS ...)?
The bot could login twice and act like 2 bots, replying twice to the command

Happened to me once

Comment: thank you in fact I had opened 2 terminal in VSCode